# Generic Parameter cannot be inferred in Closure

Tags: ios, swift, generics, closures

Right now i am trying to create a network layer class on the `AlamoFire` and `AlamofireObjectMapper` library. I have created one method for get request here is the following code

```
func getRequest<T: BaseMappable>(_ url : String,
                                 success: @escaping (DataResponse<T>) -> Void,
                                 failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) -> Void {

    self.request(url, method: .get).responseObject{ (response : DataResponse<T>) in

        success(response as DataResponse<T>)
    }        
}
```

I have imported following library in the project

```
import Alamofire
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import ObjectMapper
```

Here is the Error which i am getting while trying to the method in the `ViewController`

[image]

Thanks in Advance for you support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing it to `(response: DataResponse <Country>)` in the block argument.

This is because your generic function doesn't know what type to use for the generic parameter and the type checker can't infer it. You help it by stating the type explicitly.

Comment: I am getting this error while changing according to above solution 

Cannot convert value of type '(Country) -> ()' to expected argument type '(DataResponse<_>) -> Void'

Comment: Sorry should be `: DataResponse<Country>)`. Edited the answer

Comment: Thanks @Alistra i had this thing before your answer but your answer is correct thanks for your effort.